# Is it safe to store user specified JSON in MongoDB as BSON object without any filtering or should I stringify before storing

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, bson

I am curious about the possibility MongoDB operator being passed as JSON to gain malicious access to the database

Comment: there's no such thing as a "JSON object", since JSON is a string

Comment: Now this is even more odd question: "should I stringfy a string?" ...

Comment: @CuriousBee your concern is regarding the data traveling in-network while you perform some operations or is it regarding unwanted access to your db?

Comment: You can possibly store JSON as _string_ data type _or_ as an _object_ (aka sub-document). The safety and security of any data in the database is subject to how you secure it. It is a matter of what kind of authentication and authorization you have setup on your database.

Answer (score 0):

BSON = Binary JSON and
JSON = Javascript Object Notation

JSON is not string, but it can be serialized in string.
MongoDB support BSON that is based on JSON.

You can save any JSON in MongoDB, but is a good practice put an application between clients and database, so you can filter malicious queries.

Read more about MongoDB:
https://www.mongodb.com/en-us

Read more about sanitization:
https://dev.to/katerakeren/data-sanitization-against-nosql-query-injection-in-mongodb-and-node-js-application-1eab